# Mac cannot preview SRT files in Finder or QuickLook view (other Mac can view file without opening)

Tags: macos, big-sur, quicklook

Does anyone have any idea why this might have happened? I suspect it has something to do with installing VLC, but I could be wrong. Is there any way I can fix this?

Setting Text Edit to open all SRT files and even AppCleaning VLC from the machine didn't fix the issue. Nor did restarting the Mac after doing these things.

Comment: It's not VLC because I have VLC installed here and can still see `.srt` files file Run `qlmanage -m plugins` in Terminal.app on both computers. There's probably a QuickLook plugin on the one where .srt files do NOT display which has 'claimed' .srt files. I'm not sure how to reset which QuickLook plugin is associated with each file extension, however.

Comment: @ TJ Luoma How would she have a QuickLook plugin installed on a clean install? And yes, I do really believe this has something to do with VLC

Comment: Some QuickLook plugins come installed with macOS, others come from later-installed apps. I've never seen one related to VLC. If you run `qlmanage -m plugins` it will show you all of the quicklook plugins currently installed. If you have a VLC one, please update the question with the full path of the plugin. Actually it might be useful to include the output of `qlmanage -m plugins` from both computers in your question.

Comment: Here's the output for QuickLook plugins for the computer with the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oaui1540mndpvsq/Output.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Here's the output for QuickLook plugins for the computer with NO issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aymnimx52t0f2vn/Output%20no%20issues.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Please *edit* your question to add additional details directly.